# mysql delete trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

so i have **3 tables** :

```
tbl_client(clientpk, name, etc)
tbl_address(address_pk, street1, street2 etc) 
tbl_client_address (client_address_pk, clientpk_fk, addresspk_fk)
```

I am not really that familiar with **triggers** well enough so perhaps someone can show me how to achieve that when i delete a client it will also delete the entry in the `tbl_client_address`. I understand this can be done through referencing, but thing is, as the `tbl_client_address` is deleted i also want the address related to that client deleted.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you using innoDB or myisam ?

Comment: i am using innoDB, initially i did a reference, but found out that if i did so, it would only delete the record that binds both the client and adress together but the address itself is still present in it's respective table.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using innodb, you can add a constraint to your main tables:

CONSTRAINT `myForeignKey` FOREIGN KEY (`typeId`)
      REFERENCES `types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

rather than having to mess around with triggers

Comment: yeah, that was my first solution, but as i found out, when i delete a record from tbl_client, it would delete the related record from tbl_client_address, however the address related to that record is still present. what am trying or wanting to achieve is when i delete the a record from the client, it will also delete the address related as well and not just the record that binds them together.

Comment: +1 ... because any time you can avoid triggers you probably should.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you want the address records removed when the client record is deleted suggests that you may not really need the tbl_client_address resolution table at all.  You only need the tbl_client_address table if a given address can in fact be associated with more than one client (and if that were the case you wouldn't want to automatically cascade deletions based on the removal of tbl_client records).  So what I'm saying is that you should think about whether it might suffice to just have a tbl_address.clientpk_fk field, delete the tbl_client_address table altogether and then use Jeff's suggested constraint to cascade tbl_client record deletions.

Comment: well actually i do need the tbl_client_address because some of them have more than 1 address (mailing, billing, hq etc). actually i got it to work referencing the fk to the main table in the tbl_client_address but that would mean when i need to do this in code i need to use the pk for tbl_client_address and not the pk for tbl_client.

Comment: just because there are more than one addresses associated with one client doesn't necessitate the tbl_client_address resolution table.  that can be handled by simply having more than one tbl_address record pointing to the tbl_client record using the foreign key.  resolution tables are needed only when there's a true multi-to-multi relationship between the two outside tables... aka clients being associated with more than one address AND addresses needing to be associated with more than one client.

Comment: yeah i understand that, i only implied my 3 tables, but in reality the address table is also used for the vendors, employees, contact persons, project locations etc. this also goes for my contact information table (phone numbers, email, fax etc). the only hurdle i had so far really was that when i delete a client, i want the addresses associated with it gone too. i could just do a DELETE * FROM tbl_client_address WHERE = id_client (and reference the FK to the main tables) but it worries me a little bit cause i don't know any pitfalls using this method.

Comment: gotcha.  the pitfall i'd worry about most is the one called "trigger", lol.  i ignored the advice to avoid using them from a more advanced database developer than me at one point in my career and had to learn the hard way that triggers really can cause some seriously frustrating issues.  there are times when they really are the best choice, but it's not often.